# Slides counter and display on each slide

Tags: css

I'm looking to integrate a custom CSS to count my DIVI slides and display a current slide number. I am using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work properly and every slide is displaying "slide number 1"

```
.slide {
  counter-reset: 
    currentslide 0 
}                

slide::before {
  counter-increment: slide;                                                                    
}
#test .et_pb_slides .et_pb_slide:before { margin-left: 100px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; bottom: 17px; }
#test .et_pb_slides .et-pb-active-slide:before { opacity: 1; }
#test .et_pb_slides .et_pb_slide:nth-child(n)::before { counter-increment: slide; content: "slide number " counter(slide) ; }
```

Is there a way to count and display the slide number of each slide?

Thank you

Comment: They may no not be incrementing due to the typo on the second selector `slide`, you are missing the dot of `.slide`.

Answer (score 0):

You're inconsistent in your naming:
You are setting/resetting "currentslide", and then incrementing and using "slide" later. They have to be the same.